# Если результат запроса пуст Access

Tags: vba, access

Создал запрос в Access и через диалоговое окно открываю его, необходимо сделать MsgBox или что то в этом роде, в том случае если по результатам запроса не будет ничего найдено.

Пробовал сделать так, ничего не происходит

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub Расчитать_Click()

If DCount("*", "Отчет", "[Цена]='" & Me!txtЦена & "'") = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Нет таких!"
Else
    MsgBox "Есть такие"
    DoCmd.OpenForm "Отчет по продажам"
End If

End Sub
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Открывайте отчет, а не форму с соответствующим параметром Where, если требуется дополнительная фильтрация

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "Отчет по продажам", , , "[Цена]=" & str(Me!txtЦена)
```

При этом я предполагаю, что сам отчет построен на запросе "Отчет" и поле `Цена` - число, а не текст, как это предполагается в `If`. И еще раз проверьте условия отбора, на картинке я вижу, что вводится номер художника, а не цена.